# Origin/justification of the condition in variation of parameters?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The method of variation of parameters (on e.g. $y"+py'+qy=g$ that yields $y=A(x)y_1 +B(x)y_2$) requires one to use, in addition to the constraint provided by the actual differential equation, one has to "summon" a constraint like $A'y_1+B'y_2=0 $ (or its n-th-order counterpart). Is it really a "summon", as in it's only there as some kind of heuristic thing that "just works", or does it have any independent -and proved- grounding?